# Passing array to javascript from Java (MVC)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a MVC application where I'm setting a ArrayList of integers in the model object.

In the JSP I'm setting this array into a hidden field - the array contains [1, 2]

```
<input type="hidden" id="matchingLevels" value="${matchForm.matchingLevels}"/>
```

then in the js I want to use this as an array

```
var matchingLevels = $('#matchingLevels').val();
console.log("Form section to display: " + matchingLevels);
for (var i = 0; i < matchingLevels.length; i++) {
        console.log("matchiong level: " + matchingLevels[i]);

}
```

but this is what is displayed in the console log (its looping over each char instead of the vals of array)

```
Form section to display: [1, 2]
matchiong level: [
matchiong level: 1
matchiong level: ,
matchiong level:  
matchiong level: 2
matchiong level: ]
```

How can i convert to a javacript array and loop over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse it:

```
JSON.parse(matchingLevels)
```

Comment: Thanks! so simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

By using JSON.Parse(yourListOfValues) to get as an object.

```
var matchingLevels =JSON.parse(matchingLevels);
console.log("Form section to display: " + matchingLevels);
for (var i = 0; i < matchingLevels.length; i++) {
    console.log("matchiong level: " + matchingLevels[i]);

}
```